# remove \n (line break) from string with python

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype

I want to remove the `\n` (line break) from a string with python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

"""
<div class="thecontent" itemprop="description"><p>Kidney stone are painful and often recurring issue that can last for weeks at a time. They are affecting around 10% of the population mostly men between ages 30 and 40. </p>\n
<h4><strong>7. Get Your Fiber</strong></h4>\n
<p>Many vegetable protein sources also have the benefit of being great sources of insoluble fiber – another effective remedy for halting the growth of existing kidney stones and preventing the formation of new ones. </p>\n
<p>While many fruits and vegetables are excellent sources of fiber, be aware that they may also contain high...</p>
</div>
"""

def get_article(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    e = soup.find('div', class_='thecontent').replace('\n', ' ')
    print(e)
```

I get this error:

```
e = soup.find('div', class_='thecontent').replace('\n', ' ')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Same things with strip method

Comment: I think that your method of replacing correct. The error `'NoneType' object is not callable`, however means that the object returned by the `soup.find()` call is `None`.

Comment: e = str(soup.find('div', class_='thecontent')).replace('\n', '')    -   this work fine

Answer (score 0):

or you can put the string into a column of a dataframe, and use a simple for loop regular expression.

don't forget to put extra backslash like this: **\\n**, because otherwise it wouldn't work.

```
df['textInColumn'] = store your string here
def replaceNN(text):
    res = []
    for sub in text: 
        res.append(sub.replace("\\n", "")) 
    text = res
    return text

df['textInColumn'] = replaceNN(df['textInColumn'])
```